# Remove lines from pandas dataframe if exists on the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to match 2 dataframes based on a few columns. After this I want to remove from the original ones the matched lines but I'm not able to get what I need. The reason I want to do this is because I will try several matches if the last one didn't succeed.

Here's my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

# Creating the first dataframe
d1 = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': [5,6]}  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)    

# Creating the second dataframe
d2 = {'col1': [1, 3], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': [5,6]}    
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

Which gives me this for df1:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
```

And this for df2:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
1     3     4     6
```

Join step:

```
# Inner join to see the matches
fields = ['col1', 'col2']  
dff = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on=fields)   

# Remove from df1 and df2 the matches ones
dfs1 = df1[~df1[fields].isin(dff)]  
dfs2 = df2[~df2[fields].isin(dff)]
```

This is the result I get for dfs1 for example:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   2.0   4.0   NaN
```

This is the result I expect:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     2     4     6
```

Any ideas? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
new_df = df1[(~df1.isin(df2)).any(1)]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
1     2     4     6
```

Comment: Oh I missed "any(1)" thanks @Chris! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can work directly with the `index` with:

```py
df1.iloc[df1.index.difference(dff.index), :]
```

Which will give:

```
   col1  col2  col3
1     2     4     6
```

Comment: Oh that's quite interesting solution, thanks! I'll check which one is faster :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Creating the dataframes
import pandas as pd

# Creating the first dataframe
d1 = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': [5,6]}  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)    

# Creating the second dataframe
d2 = {'col1': [1, 3], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': [5,6]}    
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)  
df1
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
df2
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
1     3     4     6


dff = df1.merge(df2,on=['col1','col2'])
dff
   col1  col2  col3_x  col3_y
0     1     3       5       5

dfs1 = df1[(~df1.col1.isin(dff.col1))&(~df1.col2.isin(dff.col2))]
    dfs1
   col1  col2  col3
1     2     4     6

dfs2 = df2[(~df2.col1.isin(dff.col1))&(~df2.col2.isin(dff.col2))]
dfs2
   col1  col2  col3
1     3     4     6
```